# how to avoid NaNs due to rounding errors

Tags: r, floating-accuracy

Consider the calculation

```
x * -3/10 + sqrt(1/20 - x^2 / 100)
```

when `x=sqrt(5)`. The sqrt argument becomes negative due to a rounding error and the result of the whole expression is `NaN`.

```
> x <- sqrt(5)
> x * -3/10 + sqrt(1/20 - x^2 / 100)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In sqrt(1/20 - sqrt(5)^2/100) : NaNs produced
```

The correct result is

```
> sqrt(5) * -3/10
[1] -0.6708204
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want the square root to return `NaN` values, one option is to just use `pmax` to make sure its argument is at least 0:

```
x * -3/10 + sqrt(pmax(0, 1/20 - x^2 / 100))
# [1] -0.6708204
```

If you wanted it to return `NaN` when the argument to `sqrt` is quite negative but 0 when it's really close to 0 but negative, then `ifelse` could help:

```
x <- sqrt(4:6)
special.sqrt <- function(x) ifelse(x < -1e-10, NaN, sqrt(pmax(0, x)))
x * -3/10 + special.sqrt(1/20 - x^2 / 100)
# [1] -0.5000000 -0.6708204        NaN
```